# Why PolarPlot can have negative $r$?

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

Suppose a simple equation in Cartesian coordinate:
$$
(x^2+ y^2)^{3/2} = x y
$$
In polar coordinate the equation becomes $r = \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta)$. When I plot both, the one in polar coordinate has two extra lobes (I plot the polar figure with $\theta \in [0.05 \pi, 1.25 \pi]$ so the "flow" of the curve is clearer).

```
figurePolar = PolarPlot[Sin[θ] Cos[θ], {θ, 0.05 π, 1.25 π}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];
figureCartesian = ContourPlot[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^3 == x y, {x, -0.4, 0.4}, {y, -0.4, 0.4}, ContourStyle -> {Green, Dashed}];
GraphicsGrid[{{figurePolar, figureCartesian}}]
```

[image: same function in polar and Cartesian coordinate]
The right one is in the Cartesian cooridnate, it is correct since $x y \geq 0$. The extra lobes in the polar (left) figure seem to be caused by Mathematica's use of negative $r$, which is against the mathematical definition. Any thoughts?

Comment: "which is against the mathematical definition" - well, that depends on your convention; for me, negative $r$ makes sense for curves like the lemniscate of Bernoulli or the spiral of Archimedes.

Comment: @J.M. So where $r = -1, \theta = \pi/4$?

Comment: Prolly you meant that when $\theta=3\pi/4$ or $\theta=-\pi/4$, you have a radius of $-1/2$.

Comment: @J.M. No, I meant to ask if we forget about the question, where does the point with polar coordinate $r = -1, \theta = \pi/4$ lays on the plane?

Comment: Well, you know the conversion from polar to Cartesian, no? Plug those values in and see for yourself.

Comment: I know the high school math. Then why don't I just have $r = 1, \theta = 5/4\pi$, so now for a single point I have two representation $r = 1, \theta = 5/4\pi$ and $r = -1, \theta = 1/4\pi$ with the last one god knows where it froms in the formula $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

Comment: Congratulations, you've discovered that polar representations for points are **not unique**. :) That point often comes up when finding intersections of polar curves; see any nice analytic geometry text for details. And of course $(1,-\pi/4)$ is also an admissible representation for the point you speak of. (FWIW, I only learned polar coordinates years after I was no longer in school. But Scouting experience already taught me the concept of distance and bearing.)

Comment: Of course, if you really want the Cartesian representation of the plot, you could just use `ContourPlot[(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2) == x y, {x,-1,1}, {y,-1,1}]`.  Your coordinate transformation is really the problem;  when you apply the transformation, you have $(r^2)^{3/2} = r^2 \cos \theta \sin \theta$, which implies that $\sqrt{r^2} = |r| = \cos \theta \sin \theta$, not $r = \cos \theta \sin \theta$.

Answer (score 7):

You can always impose this constraint with the option [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html):

```
PolarPlot[Sin[θ] Cos[θ], {θ, 0, 2π}]
```

[image]

```
PolarPlot[Sin[θ] Cos[θ], {θ, 0, 2π}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, θ, r}, r > 0]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's the way to plot the same figure as the Cartesian one, but still I am wondering why negative $r$ is allowed, the Cartesian figure is the correct one and accurately represent the function, I don't want it that after changing to polar coordinate somehow "extra features" get added.

Answer (score 5):

`PolarPlot` purposely accepts negative radii values as well as angles beyond the range 0 to 2$\pi$. See, for example, the `PolarPlot` [documentation here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolarPlot.html) showing `PolarPlot[Sin[3 t], {t, 0, Pi}]`, which returns this three lobe structure including values below the x-axis (even though the plot angles are only in the range 0 to Pi).

[image]

Since any real value of $(r,\theta)$ still maps to a unique plot point in $(x,y)$, there is no inherent problem with uniqueness in terms of plotting.

Not restricting the range of $(r,\theta$) also helps in creating more intricate plots, including spirals (as J.M. commented above) and even flowers (as shown in the documentation examples).

```
PolarPlot[{Sin[6 θ], Cos[6 θ]}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

However, as discussed here on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarCoordinates.html), this means that "polar coordinates aren't inherently unique", because the inverse transform $(x,y)\to(r,\theta)$ is not uniquely defined (unless the range of $r,\theta$ is restricted).

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that, I am wondering about the inconsistency between the polar and Cartesian of the same function -- with the Cartesian being the correct one.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with "over defining"; negative $r$ can be interpreted geometrically just as well as positive $r$. Just go in the direction opposite to that for positive $r$.

Comment: Thanks @J.M. You are right; "over defining" could be misleading. I have edited to say  "not restricting" instead and added a brief explanation about the range of $(r,\theta)$.

Comment: Much better, now I can upvote. :)

Comment: " Just go in the direction opposite to that for positive". So you agree with a  both  inclusive generalisation ?

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to restrict to positive radii:

```
PolarPlot[Max[Sin[θ] Cos[θ], 0], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: But then my mathematical function in Cartesian coordinate should be $(x^2+y^2)^{3/2} = \max (x y, 0)$, which changes the definition (it should not).

Answer (score 1):

$$  r = \pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2} =f(\theta)$$

Basically when you entered into polar coordinates usage you had implicatively or unwittingly accepted that all radius vectors can be either positive or negative.

It is consequential to the above artefact, negative sign makes complete sense to *all* polar curves of two dimensions. It has nothing to do with any particular polar curve or Mathematica.

That means you had also bargained for antisymmetric (with respect to origin)curve:

$$  (x,y) = \pm r\ (cos \theta, sin \theta ).$$

In Mathematica there are options for PlotRegion etc., as others mention.

EDIT1

That any polar curve can always be associated with its (origin mirrored ) counterpart as its dual...is sometimes disconcerting.

For example starting with  the Cartesian circle

$$ (x - h)^2 + (y -k)^2= R^2 $$

if we convert to polar and accept both signs and reconvert to Cartesian coordinates, it tantamounts to accepting its dual

$$ (x + h)^2 + (y +k)^2= R^2 $$

as the polar counterpart.This is obtained by rotating the circle about origin through $ \pi .$

We may generalize:

**Every polar plot has its conjugate or  dual plot $(r \rightarrow -r )$ which is polar symmetric with the origin.**

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer is the closest to the point, seems I didn't explain my question well. Anyway, all books have polar coordinate defined as $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, \theta = atan2(y/x)$, so $r$ must be positive by definition. For example, I know exactly where the points $r = 1, \theta = \pm \pi$ are on the polar plane, but I don't where to locate $r = -1, \theta = \pm \pi$.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer above, it is on the other side of the origin,

Comment: $r=\cos\theta $ are $two$ circles, please note in this context.

Comment: All books have r positive by definition? You've never explored optics...

Comment: @John, and I gotta say, the analytic geometry books I've seen all mention that $r$ can be negative. OTOH, they're old, and maybe the OP's newfangled books now have restrictions in place.

Comment: Not by definition, but  by convention in this context at least at the introductory stages. Ok, please enlighten with some optically negative distance examples.

Comment: @Narasimham https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature_(optics)

Comment: Mathematica doesn't know which books you're reading. If you define the radius to be positive, it's your responsibility to express that restriction rather than insist that the software enforce it on everybody.

Comment: Not insisting. I was in the same line of thought as the OP earlier. I simply shared a viewpoint. With some experience with Mathematica with polar plots thought it would perhaps be helpful.